# No se permite conexión al servidor MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-workbench

después de buscar por la web alguna solución a mi problema, finalmente me decido a escribir por acá, esperando ayuda de ustedes.

Tengo una base de datos local, creada con MySql Workbench. Me conecto a ella desde C#, y cuando quiero probar la conección, se me devuelve el siguiente error:

> Host [Nombre de mi Pc] is not allowed to connect to this MySql server

Mi cadena de conexión en C# la tengo así:

```
cadena = "Server=127.0.0.1; Database=nombreBaseDatos; Uid=root; Pwd=contraseña";
```

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Ya revisaste que `bind-address` tenga valor `0.0.0.0` en `mysqld.cnf`?

Comment: @Alfabravo, lo revisé, pero no tengo dicha linea en el archivo. La agregué, pero tampoco me da solución alguna.

Comment: Qué versión de MySQL estás usando?

Comment: MySql Server 8.0

Comment: ¿Tienes asignado algún usuario con privilegios? por ejemplo: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@ip_o_nombreEquipo IDENTIFIED BY contraseña

Comment: @JavierTarrazona También lo hice, y nada. continúo con el problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que al definir `127.0.0.1` quiera conectarse de forma remota, con lo cual al no estar habilitado no lo permita

Prueba de usar

```
Server=localhost;
```

[C# Mysql connection working only on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16505897/c-sharp-mysql-connection-working-only-on-localhost)

Si cambias el `bind-address` para habilitar que escuche de forma remota

[Cómo permitir el acceso remoto a una base de datos MySQL](https://geekytheory.com/como-permitir-el-acceso-remoto-a-una-base-de-datos-mysql)

[Set up a remote MySQL database connection](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/mysql_remote.html)

recuerda reiniciar el servicio para que tome la nueva configuracion, por eso veras que en las guias menciona usar:

```
service mysqld restart
```